# How do I implement a web search using Hadoop/Hbase?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

How do I implement a web search using Hadoop/Hbase. Can anyone please provide me some guidelines or tutorial just to get started?

Comment: Hi Priya, have you found any answer to your problem? Even I am also facing same problem. I have other problem of implementing web crawler using hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

this article is about map-Reduce, and it gives some examples on implementing principals of information retrieval using map-reduce.

http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html

You might also want to check out Apache Lucene, which is an open source information retrieval system, and Apache Solr

Answer (score 1):

Try lily project this deals with indexing hbase table data and the indexed data can easily be used for implimentation of search. here is the link that you may refer

http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html

Lily unifies Apache HBase, Hadoop and Solr into a comprehensively integrated, interactive data platform with easy-to-use access APIs, a high-level data model and schema language, flexible, real-time indexing and the expressive search power of Apache Solr. Best of all, Lily is open source

Answer (score 0):

@Yash:

For Hbase:
Read chapter on Hbase from [Definitive guide](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs402/2011/book/2009-Book-Hadoop%20the%20Definitive%20Guide.pdf). Then read [Apache Hbase guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book/book.html). This will make you more clear about Hbase.

[Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) can help you to send multiple queries to server for testing purpose.

[Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a open source hadoop based web crawler. [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a search platform which leverages lucene internally. You might peek into these to understand their design and implement your web search app.